# Что за значение [System process] возвращает Process32First

Tags: c++, winapi

Что это обозначает и зачем оно вообще нужно? Может где то используется?

Comment: Справку по [функции](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684834(v=vs.85).aspx) читали? Где Вы увидели `[System process]`?

Comment: читал, а вы читали?

Comment: Поясните, о каком значении идет речь?

Comment: [System process], если вы не понимаете о чем речь, то выведите список процессов и самый первый из них будет именно он

Answer (score 1):

Функция [`Process32First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834(v=vs.85).aspx) задает начало перебора списка процессов, и в частности обеспечивает заполнение через указать во втором аргументе информации о первом процессе в системе.

```
BOOL WINAPI Process32First(
  _In_    HANDLE           hSnapshot,
  _Inout_ LPPROCESSENTRY32 lppe
);
```

Структура [`PROCESSENTRY32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684839(v=vs.85).aspx) имеет поле `szExeFile`, которое и содержит упомянутое в вопросе строковое значение `"[System process]"`. Также можно обратить внимание на идентификатор этого процесса (поле `th32ProcessID`), он будет равен `0`.

Данный процесс на самом деле не является каким-либо реальным процессом, и по сути отражает насколько система свободна для выполнения каких-то других задач. Его существование позволяет упростить механизм работы планировщика процессов. В диспетчере задач Windows данный "процесс" называется "Бездействие системы" ("System Idle Process").

Comment: "и по сути отражает насколько система свободна" - а как она отражает? Каким то полем структуры PROCESSENTRY32?
Она используется где то именно разработчиком?